# datagridview rowvalidating cancel

Tags: c#, datagridview, event-handling

I've seen several posts here and on other sites that are similar to my question/problem, but have never really seen anything directly on-target and with a good answer (if I missed one in my search, please point me to it!).  Please forgive me if this is long, but I want to give as complete/accurate a descriptions as I can...  Thanks in advance for your help!!

I have a Windows form with side-by-side datagridviews (dgdApplications & dgdEligibleFiles). dgdApplications is set for FullRowSelect and validation (CausesVailidation = true). dgdEligibleFiles contains a list of files & file info, and a checkbox column - if a row is checked, the file it represents is "assigned" to the selected row in dgdApplications (a row/application in dgdApplications may have many files assigned to it).  If a user has altered his assignments in dgdEligibleFiles (checked/unchecked one/more rows) without clicking the Save button at form-bottom, and then clicks another row in dgdApplications, I currently use dgdApplications_RowValidating to pop a messagebox and verify that the user wants to proceed to the newly-selected application/row without saving changes.  If the "No" button is clicked, I call e.Cancel to stay in the original row.  If "Yes", I want to proceed with dgdApplications_MouseClick on the new row, which will do the following: clear the checkboxes in dgdEligibleFiles, retrieve the list of files for the newly selected app in dgdApplications, and update checked/selected values in the underlying list bound to dgdEligibleFiles (followed by dgdEligibleFiles.Refresh()).

My problem: When the messagebox is displayed in dgdApplications.RowValidating and the user chooses "Yes" to continue (abandoning changes in dgdEligibleFiles and going to the new row in dgdApplications), dgdApplications_MouseClick does not get executed and nothing changes in dgdEligbleFiles.  How can I get dgdApplications_MouseClick to execute?

```
void dgdApplications_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (assgnmtChgd && (MessageBox.Show("You will lose unsaved changes - continue?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles the selection of an application when it's datagridview row is clicked
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void dgdApplications_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Reset the DisplayAssignedOnly checkbox so all dgdEligibleFiles rows will be unhidden and displayed
    chkDispAssgndOnly.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
    ClearFilesGrid();

    dgdApplications.CurrentRow.Selected = true;
    currentAppRowID = dgdApplications.CurrentRow.Index;
    currentAppRecID = (int)dgdApplications.CurrentRow.Cells["appIDColumn"].Value;
    dgdEligibleFiles.ClearSelection();
    dgdEligibleFiles.CurrentCell = null;
    MatchAssignedFiles(currentAppRecID);

    dgdEligibleFiles.Refresh();

    //Set the indicator showing that no assignments have been changed
    assgnmtChgd = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is that your click event occurs before RowValidating so you have to do your process in another event like cellleave

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
//you can access to index column and row to do your process
    dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style
        .SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Hassan, thanks for your reply! I'm having a little trouble with it, though. When I put break points in both the RowValidating and MouseClick event handlers, I never see MouseClick execute - I only see RowValidating.  So, evidence seems to sugest that RowValidating executes first - that seems to be confirmed in this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240221/DataGridView-Event-Sequences. I'd appreciate your thoughts (and anyone else's) as to why I see only the RowValidating and not the MouseClick, given what you said.  In the meantime, I will look at the "leave" events as you suggested.

Comment: you are welcome so if my answer is good (only if it is working) thank to mark it ;-)

Comment: I'm not clear on which process you think I should do in a Leave event.  I don't see how I can put the clear/list-retrieval/checkbox-setting for dgdEligibleFiles in a Leave event of dgdApplications - that would be putting the cart before the horse, as the potential "cancel" would happen after the processing for the newly selected row has already occurred. And the Leave events don't seem to offer the option to cancel. Am I missing something?

Comment: Bump - no one? I honestly don't understand how the previous suggestion could work, and I'd greatly appreciate explanations or elaboration.

Comment: I also tried taking the code from the mouseclick event, wrapping a method around it, and calling it from both the mouseclick and rowvalidating events.  It still doesn't get called from the rowvalidating event if the ueser elects to continue - why is that?